# How can I keep connection to server using socket?

Tags: c#, sockets, networkstream

I have connection to the server. After connected successfully, I can see the connection via CMD netstat command `netstat -a -n`. But after about 21 seconds, the connection changing from `ESTABLISHED` to `CLOSE_WAIT`. I want to the connection always is `ESTABLISHED`. How can I do it?

This is from netstat command, the result in the first time and second time.

```
   TCP    192.168.10.12:50148    10.10.10.120:3000     ESTABLISHED 
   TCP    192.168.10.12:50148    10.10.10.120:3000     CLOSE_WAIT
```

This is my snipped code in C#

```
private void _connect()
{
    var IpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.10.10.120"), 3000);
    var client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
    client.SendTimeout = 60;
    client.ReceiveTimeout = 60;
    try
    {
        client.Connect(IpEndPoint);
        int byteCount = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
        while (true)
        {
            byteCount = client.Receive(bytes);
            if (byteCount == 0) //not receive anything from server, client will send dummy data to server
            {
                byte[] data_send = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hi, dummy data");
                client.Send(data_send);
            }
            else //receive data from server, write it to log files.
            {
                byte[] byte_rec = new byte[byteCount];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, byte_rec, 0, byteCount);
                txt_log.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byte_rec);
            }  
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I try debug more time, but it only can be run few seconds, after that the connection will be changed from `ESTABLISHED` to `CLOSE_WAIT`. The code above never show exception message.

Meantime, i have other option using `TcpClient`

```
private void _connect()
{
            TcpClient client1 = new TcpClient();
            try
            {               
                client1.Connect("10.10.10.120", 3000);
                NetworkStream stream1 = client1.GetStream();
                var bytes = new byte[256];
                while (true)
                {
                    int numbyte = stream1.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    if (numbyte == 0)
                    {
                        byte[] data_send = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hi, dummy data");
                        stream1.Write(data_send, 0, data_send.Length);   
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        byte[] byte_rec = new byte[numbyte];
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, byte_rec, 0, numbyte);
                        txt_log.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byte_rec);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
}
```

With this code using Tcpclient, the connection still about 20 seconds, after that the connection will be appear, not show `ESTABLISHED`  or `CLOSE_WAIT` when i use netstat command to check. But it have exception message is `Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine`.

So far, I found some option and enhancement my code. However, when I debug, I can see stream with properties `DataAvailable` is true at the first time loop. After that, the second time loop, it's always is false. If don't put break point and run with this code, it's can keep connection about more than 10min. But when I put break point at this line `numberOfBytesRead = stream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);`, it only run at the first time loop, without next time because stream is false. The time delay when run first time to second time loop about 52s. After that, the connection is break. I get this exception `: 'Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.'` . Can you tell me why stream changed from true to false after first time loop ?. This way stuck and let my code is wrong.

```
 private async void _connect()
  {
            var serverEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(_ip), _port);
            client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            try
            {
                client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
                client.Connect(serverEndpoint);
                client.NoDelay = true;
                client.SendTimeout = 60000;
                client.ReceiveTimeout = 60000;
                byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[1024];
                int numberOfBytesRead = 0;
                bool _flag = false;             
                while (true)
                {
                    stream = new NetworkStream(client); //create stream based on socket
                    if (stream.CanRead)
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            if (_flag)
                            {
                                numberOfBytesRead = 0;
                                goto receiveskip;
                            }
                            if (numberOfBytesRead == 0) //send dummy data to server first
                            {
                                byte[] data_dummy = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("dummy_abc");
                                stream.Write(data_dummy, 0, data_dummy.Length);
                                stream.Flush();
                            }
                            numberOfBytesRead = stream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
                            byte[] bytes_rec = new byte[numberOfBytesRead];
                            Buffer.BlockCopy(myReadBuffer, 0, bytes_rec, 0, numberOfBytesRead);                         
                            //client receive data from server at the first time, after sent dummy_abc to server
                            if(bytes_rec.Length == 14) 
                            {
                                txt_log.Text += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes_rec); //write to textbox
                            }
                            //receive data from server at second time and so on. 
                            //After server get data from client and reply first time, server will send data
                            //server will send data with bytes lengh more 14
                            if (bytes_rec.Length > 14)
                            {
                                byte[] data_rep = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Ok, thank server"); //client reply to server 
                                stream.Write(data_rep, 0, data_rep.Length);
                                stream.Flush();
                                _flag = true;
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        while (stream.DataAvailable);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Cannot read from this NetworkStream.");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
  }
```

Comment: What do you see if you run Wireshark?

Comment: Are you getting any data at all? This code expects that the server sends data without you ever asking for anything.

Comment: @PMF , Yes, sometimes the server send dummy data , like ```Hi client```.

Comment: It seems like the [server closed](https://superuser.com/a/173542) the connection. Is the server in your control? What does it do?

Comment: Firstly, why are you using raw sockets, why not use `TcpClient`? And if you don't send any data then you need to use a `KeepAlive`, which again is much easier using `TcpClient`. Furthermore, are you aware that `Receive` may not get the exact data that you send, it may be split or joined in any number of ways, as TCP is just a stream of bytes. `if (byteCount == 0)` doesn't make sense because if you get no bytes it means the socket is closed.

Comment: @Dai, we can without with Wireshark

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride, the server always open with the port 3000, it is listening any client to connect , if have connection the server will send some dummy data to client.

Comment: And what does it do after sending the dummy data? Does it keep the connection open? Will it actually read the data the client is sending to it? Can we see the code?

Comment: @Charlieface , I have through about ```TcpClient``` and ```NetworkStream``` ago, but in this case, the socket with ```Send``` and ```Receive``` is easier.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride , i'm so sorry, can not show the server code, but i know what's the exactly in the server . It's listening from client, sometime it will be send dummy data first and sometime not send , just waiting data from client send first .

Comment: The thing is your client is bombarding the server with `"Hi, dummy data"` multiple times per second. If the server never actually reads those bytes it might get clogged, but that's just a guess. Or maybe `Send()` blocks until the server acknowledges the client data? If that never happens the connection might just time out? I'm not a TCP expert.

Comment: If the server doesn't send anything then `client.Receive(bytes);` will block forever, or until the socket is closed. What do you expect to happen here?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride we have condition to checking, if server never send data to client, the client will send dummy data , not like ```ddos```, else client not send , right ?

Comment: @Charlieface , the server have send data , but seem in range time, that's why i said that sometimes, the server send data first and not send first.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not understanding you, perhaps mistranslation? Can you please be clearer?

Comment: Didn't you get an exception?

Comment: @shingo without socket, just only when using ```tcpclient```

Comment: @Charlieface probably you read faster more than me or I didn't explain more detail to you, sorry for this.  I have added more detail in my post, look at them again.

Comment: Same problem with the way you used `TcpClient`, you are expecting `Read` to terminate at some point but there is no timeout. If the number of bytes read is `0` it means the socket is closed, so of course you get an exception. See my answer.

Comment: No exception with socket?! Didn't even time out? Then do you know where is the code blocked?

Comment: @shingo , as i said before. It can be connection and the connection i checking via CMD netstat command, i counter about 20 seconds, and after that change from establish to closewait

Comment: What I mean is on which line did the code/loop stop.

Comment: Unless you have some specific reason for using TCP I would recommend some higher level protocol that takes care of most of the [issues using TCP](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html). As an example, MQTT can handle "keep alive" internally.

Comment: @shingo, As i said that before, not have line do loop stop. It's run normal, can established, after 20 seconds , the connection change to close_wait

Comment: @JonasH, After do this one, i have read Socket and TcpClient, the issue just after connection is established, it's always changed to close_wait after 20 seconds.

Comment: Do you want to tell me that your socket status is already CLOSE_WAIT, but the loop is not stopped on any line, so it is still receiving data from the server? Is this possible?

Comment: @shingo, probably this line ```byteCount = await stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, cts.Token);``` , when i run in debug mode, i put breakpoint at this line, the step by step i do like this, 1)start it, it run and never break at this breakpoint, 2)check in CMD , the connection is established . 3) check in CMD, the connection is close_wait, 4) code break at breakpoint with byteCount  = 0 ,  that it.

Comment: @shingo I have updated more description and idea.

Comment: @Charlieface   I get more enhancement in my code and updated. But seem get stuck with stream.DataAvailable after first time loop.

Comment: I have already told you the issue with your code. It's blocking forever. Even if you use `DataAvailable`, if there is no data it will end the loop.

Comment: So, how it can run established more than 10min in this time . The first code is just 20second, but with lasted my code, it's can run 10min. Sorry, but I'm confusing in this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after more time to debug and enhancement, I get my resolve by myself, I'm not sure if you all get same issue, but it working well until now for me. The key in here , just look at the finally code and changed something. Like this below, thank for all advices.

```
private async void _connect()
  {
            var serverEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(_ip), _port);
            var client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            try
            {
                client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
                client.SendTimeout = 180000;
                client.ReceiveTimeout = 180000;         
                await client.ConnectAsync(serverEndpoint);
                byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[1024];
                int numberOfBytesRead = 0;
                bool _flag = false;             
                var stream = new NetworkStream(client); 
                while (true)
                {
                            if (_flag)
                            {
                                numberOfBytesRead = 0;
                                goto receiveskip;
                            }
                            if (numberOfBytesRead == 0) //send dummy data to server first
                            {
                                byte[] data_dummy = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("dummy_abc");
                                await stream.WriteAsync(data_dummy, 0, data_dummy.Length);
                                await stream.FlushAsync();
                                _flag = true;
                            }
                            receiveskip:
                            numberOfBytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
                            byte[] bytes_rec = new byte[numberOfBytesRead];
                            Buffer.BlockCopy(myReadBuffer, 0, bytes_rec, 0, numberOfBytesRead);                         
                            //client receive data from server at the first time, after sent dummy_abc to server
                            if(bytes_rec.Length == 14) 
                            {
                                txt_log.Text += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes_rec); //write to textbox
                                _flag = true;
                                goto receiveskip;
                            }
                            //receive data from server at second time and so on. 
                            //After server get data from client and reply first time, server will send data
                            //server will send data with bytes lengh more 14
                            if (bytes_rec.Length > 14)
                            {
                                byte[] data_rep = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Ok, thank server"); //client reply to server 
                                await stream.WriteAsync(data_rep, 0, data_rep.Length);
                                await stream.FlushAsync();
                                _flag = true;
                                goto receiveskip;
                            }
                            if (bytes_rec.Length == 0)
                            {
                              break;
                            }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                client.Close();
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a multitude of issues here:

- Use `TcpClient` instead of raw sockets, it's much easier.
- You need to dispose your socket.
- Your comment `//not receive anything from server, client will send dummy data to server` doesn't make sense. The Read does not have a timeout, so it will just block forever, until the socket gets closed due to no data, at which point you *will* receive `0`. Perhaps you need a timeout?
- TCP KeepAlive messages have a minimum timeout of 2 hours, so it's probably not worth messing with them. The server is closing the connection far earlier.
- Be aware that a single `Send` does not necessarily result in a single `Read`. It may be merged or split in any number of ways.
- Use `async` `await` as this will keep your UI responsive.

```cs
private async Task _connect()
{
    try
    {
        var IpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.10.10.120"), 3000);
        using var (client = new TcpClient())
        {
            client.SendTimeout = 60;
            client.ReceiveTimeout = 60;
            await client.ConnectAsync(IpEndPoint);
            using (var stream = client.GetStream())
            {
                await Read(stream);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private async Task Read(NetworkStream stream)
{
    int byteCount = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(someTimeoutHere))
            {
                byteCount = await stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, cts.Token);
                if (byteCount == 0)  // socket was closed
                    return;

                txt_log.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, byteCount);
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        //not receive anything from server, client will send dummy data to server
        {
            var bytesToWrite = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hi, dummy data");
            await stream.WriteAsync(bytesToWrite, 0, bytesToWrite.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Charlieface, get more detail from my post, i tried with your suggest ```tcpclient``` before. But seem look like not working well. 
By the way, i use C#7.3 , not available with your code

Comment: Yeah you need to use the old style `using` block, see edit.

Comment: Oh really, seem your code missing some arguments at 3 lines ```byteCount = await stream.Read(bytes, cts.Token); var size = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hi, dummy data", bytes.AsSpan());await client.WriteAsync(bytes.AsMemory(0, size));``` First line missing one parameter , second line overload parameter, three line should be stream.WriteAsync

Comment: Are you on .NET Framework 4.8 still? Yes you can't use those overloads, need to use older overloads with the array start and length.

Comment: Hi @Charlieface, I try with your mention, It's same my case. It can be connection, I can see in netstat command, but it's changed to close_wait after 20 seconds. Your code run normal not have exception .

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you be clearer, seems to be a mistranslation because I can't understand you.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I mean I want to keep the connection always is ```ESTABLISHED``` status. By the ways, the connection just only about 20 seconds, after that it's changed to CLOSE_WAIT. Can you try with your code and check netstat command parallel ?, you will see the connection is ESTABLISHED, and you wait about 20s,  check netstat command again and see the connection change to CLOSE_WAIT

Answer (score 1):

It can be confirmed that your problem is that the server closed the connection, causing the status of the client socket to change from `ESTABLISHED` to `CLOSE_WAIT`. Usually, if the status becomes `CLOSE_WAIT`, it will immediately close itself (that is, you cannot see this connection in netstat) and cause `Socket.Receive` and `Socket.Send` to throw an exception. However, you told me that your first piece of code did not have any exceptions, and I can only speculate that this method has been blocked somewhere so that the socket cannot be closed. Of course, this requires you to debug to know which line it is.

**So the key problem is: Why does the server close your connection?** Since you didn't provide the server code, you will need to find the answer yourself.

Finally, the key point is to compare your updated third piece of code with the previous first and second pieces. The biggest difference is that you **sent some data before reading** in the new code, so I can boldly guess that your server needs the client to send some data after connecting to it in order to function properly (in other word the server is also calling `Receive` first).

Anyway please check your server code.

Comment: You are right in this case. After check more time, the right way should be like this. 1) client connect to server. 2) If the connection is established, client send test data (dummy data) to server first . 3) After server get test data from client, it will be reply. 4) Next the server will send some data to client and wait reply from client . 5) so on keep connection.  Besides, you can see and determine what's we have and need to adjust again.